# h3 font color not changing

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on a project in one of my classes (History) where I have to summarize the Treaty of Paris in a newsletter, video, etc.

One choice is a website, which I am doing.

I'm trying to make  ("American Colonists rebel against Great Britain") to be a grayish color.

When I put it in the  tags,it just... doesn't work.
It changes the font size to 15, but doesn't make it gray.

Any help would be appreciated.

I've tried:
- !important
- Putting inline styles
- Different colors
- Assigning a class to have the gray color and applying that class to h3

```
<head>
<title>
</title>
<style>
h3 {
     color: "#434343";
}

. . .

<h3>American Colonists rebel against Great Britain</h3>
```

I expect h3 to be gray (#434343) but instead it stays the normal black (#000000)

Comment: try  remove quotes `""` like this `color: #434343;`

Comment: @SASSY_ROG Please don't recommend `!important` to fix these kinds of things; people who maintain your code in the future will thank you.

Comment: @SASSY_ROG That actually worked... I'm honestly not great at HTML so I have these problems all the time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

typo error remove a `quote` on color property

```
h3 {
     color: #434343;
}
```

Comment: Please don't answer typo questions; we have a specific close reason for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do inline

```
<h3 style="color:#434343;">American Colonists rebel against Great Britain</h3>
```